# Tool for counting lines in C# functions

Tags: c#, refactoring

I have inherited a C# project.  One of the files has over 900 lines.

Is there a tool that will list the functions in a C# file and their line count?

I'm using LOC as a criteria for refactoring.

My internet searches have not shown anything (only how to count lines in a file or LOC counting applications).